# Trying to read an int counter into a string method[java]

Tags: java

I am trying to read a counter variable into another method(printPartiallyFilledArray) in order to calculate and print the correct number of string elements in an array. However whenever I try to compile, it says that I cannot due to being unable to locate the calculate variable. How can I make it so the second method knows the value of the counter variable?

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    // Instantiate a String array that can contain 10 items.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
    String[] array = new String[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int counter = 0;


    // Read names of subjects into this array
    // and count how many have been read in.
    // There may be fewer than 10.
    System.out.println("Please enter a subject name or enter q to quit: ");
    String subject = keyboard.nextLine(); 

    while(subject.equals("q")!=true && counter<ARRAY_SIZE)
    {   
        array[counter] = subject;
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Please enter a subject name or enter q to quit: ");
        subject = keyboard.nextLine();

    }

    // Call printPartiallyFilledArray to print the names in the array.
   printPartiallyFilledArray(array);

}


/**
 * Method printPartiallyFilledArray prints the String values 
 * in a partially-filled array, one per line.  Only the 
 * significant items in the array should be printed.
 * 
 * @param array the array of Strings to be printed on the screen
 * @param count the number of items in the partially-filled array
 */
    public static void printPartiallyFilledArray(String[] array)
    {

     System.out.println("The array elements: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        System.out.println(array[i]); }

    }
```

}

Comment: declare it outside of your main method

Comment: Okay thank you, I will try this.

Comment: Your code builds and runs fine on my local IntelliJ setup here.  What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: Thank you so much Mohammad, I declared it outside of my main method and it worked. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Tim, the error I was getting stated that it could not locate the counter variable. I followed Mohammad's instructions and declared it outside of my main method and it is working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to inform the method about the value of counter:

1. Define the variable counter globally, outside the main function. This will allow it to know the value of the globally updated counter variable at all times.

for instance:

```
public class Solution{
public static int counter =0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
    ---do things as before----
    }

    public static void printPartiallyFilledArray(String[] array){
    ---do things as before----
    }
}
```

2. Pass the value of the counter to the function printPartiallyFilledArray by redefining the function parameters as:

   ```
   printPartiallyFilledArray(String[] array, int counter)
   ```

and calling it in your code by calling

```
printPartiallyFilledArray(array, counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the counter variable with the

```
public static void printPartiallyFilledArray(String[] array, int counter)
```

and use it.